# undefined method `joins' for #<Arel::SelectManager>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, arel

I'm trying to convert this query from raw SQL to Arel (6.0.0), but I'm running into problems that I never had before Arel was rebuilt from the ground up in later versions. The error I'm getting, specifically, is:

`` undefined method `joins' for #<Arel::SelectManager> ``

This error occurs are starting an ActiveRecord `joins` query, and then appending another `joins`. Any idea how I should combine joins with ActiveRecord (and Arel predicates?)

The new code:

```
v = o.joins(Vote.table_name).on(Vote.arel_table[:voteable_type].eq(o.to_s).and(Vote.arel_table[:voteable_id].eq(o.arel_table[o.primary_key])))
        v = v.joins(self.class.base_class.table_name).on(self.base_class.arel_table[self.class.base_class.primary_key].eq(o.arel_table[p[0]]))
        v = v.where(self.class.base_class.areal_table[self.class.base_class.primary_key].eq(self.id))
```

converted from:

```
v = o.where(["#{self.class.base_class.table_name}.#{self.class.base_class.primary_key} = ?", self.id])
v = v.joins("INNER JOIN #{Vote.table_name} ON #{Vote.table_name}.voteable_type = '#{o.to_s}' AND #{Vote.table_name}.voteable_id = #{o.table_name}.#{o.primary_key}")
v = v.joins("INNER JOIN #{self.class.base_class.table_name} ON #{self.class.base_class.table_name}.#{self.class.base_class.primary_key} = #{o.table_name}.#{p[0]}")
```

`o` is an ActionModel Instance.
If anyone's interested, this if for use in the `thumbs_up` gem.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Thats a huge mess but I believe you should be able to start by simply `Vote.joins(:a, :b, :c).where(a: { some_column: 'foo'})`. Unless you have rather special cases you don't need to tell Rails how to create join queries. And mutating assigments are a bad code smell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `join` in Arel not `joins`

```
vote_t = Vote.arel_table    
other_t = self.class.base_class.arel_table
v = o.join(vote_t).on(vote_t[:voteable_type].eq(o.to_s).and(vote_t[:voteable_id].eq(o.arel_table[o.primary_key])))
v = v.join(other_t).on(other_t[self.class.base_class.primary_key].eq(o.arel_table[p[0]]))
v = v.where(other_t[self.class.base_class.primary_key].eq(self.id))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
v = o.joins(Vote.table_name).on(Vote.arel_table[:voteable_type].eq(o.to_s).and(Vote.arel_table[:voteable_id].eq(o.arel_table[o.primary_key])))
```

From the looks of it, your first line starts with `o` which I'm guessing is some type of `ActiveRecord` model. [ActiveRecord defines the joins method as you already know](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins).

However the output from the first line is not another `ActiveRecord` model, but instead an instance of `Arel::SelectManager`. The problem then, is that `joins` is not defined for that instance, instead you want the [`join` method](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/arel/Arel/SelectManager#join-instance_method).

Anything more than that is difficult to suss out since your code is lacking in details (if you could provide more details I can potentially expand on my answer.)

`<opinion>` If I were to stumble upon either piece of code, I'd likely try to write it out in raw SQL, since both examples are difficult to understand `</opinion>`

Comment: Thanks for your help! It was (very close to) raw SQL as you can see - the issue being that it needs to work on 3 DB engines (MySQL, Postgres and SQLite3), and so I thought relying on Arel to transform the SQL appropriately was a better aim than coming up with 3 different SQL statements (the syntax is different for all 3 in this case).